# Why was does Python3 differentiate between ascii and utf-8

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, language-lawyer

All the `ascii` characters can be represented by `utf-8` (the first seven bits of space). Using exclusively `utf-8` could simplify `string handling` greatly. Granted `utf-8` is not a fixed length format and therefore has certain performance penalties with respect to `ascii` but I have the feeling python normally goes for `pythonic` before performance.

**My question**: Has it ever been addressed why `python3` implements strings this way instead of `utf-8` exclusively? Thereby not representing it as a bitstream with different representations but always with the `utf-8` encoding.

I'm not looking for personal opinions from SO users but for `PEP`'s or a transcript from the dictator addressing this very point.

Comment: Python3 *does* use utf-8 encoding by default, so I have no idea what your question is really asking ...

Comment: @wim I tried to make it more clear. While it uses utf-8 as default there is still the binary string around which can for example lead to nasty bugs when trying to do string compares. My question is: why was the language revision not designed in a way that only allows for one type of representation.

Comment: It *was* designed that way, and the one type of representation is the `str` representation.  Both `'utf-8'` and `'ascii'` are encodings.  There is no such thing as a utf-8 str object.

Comment: @wim, your right I meant encoding. However I still have the feeling adds less value than trouble. Therefore I was still wondering about the reasoning.

Comment: You still don't have a coherent question here.  If you are asking why python doesn't enforce only using the utf-8 encoding, that's because we need software which is able to communicate with files or services that are using other encodings too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/):

> ## Rationale
>
> There are two classes of complaints about the current implementation
> of the unicode type: on systems only supporting UTF-16, users complain
> that non-BMP characters are not properly supported. On systems using
> UCS-4 internally (and also sometimes on systems using UCS-2), there is
> a complaint that Unicode strings take up too much memory - especially
> compared to Python 2.x, where the same code would often use ASCII
> strings (i.e. ASCII-encoded byte strings). With the proposed approach,
> ASCII-only Unicode strings will again use only one byte per character;
> while still allowing efficient indexing of strings containing non-BMP
> characters (as strings containing them will use 4 bytes per
> character).
>
> One problem with the approach is support for existing applications
> (e.g. extension modules). For compatibility, redundant representations
> may be computed. Applications are encouraged to phase out reliance on
> a specific internal representation if possible. As interaction with
> other libraries will often require some sort of internal
> representation, the specification chooses UTF-8 as the recommended way
> of exposing strings to C code.
>
> For many strings (e.g. ASCII), multiple representations may actually
> share memory (e.g. the shortest form may be shared with the UTF-8 form
> if all characters are ASCII). With such sharing, the overhead of
> compatibility representations is reduced. If representations do share
> data, it is also possible to omit structure fields, reducing the base
> size of string objects.

---

If it is not clear from the above text:

- We want most strings representation to be space efficient
- We want efficient indexing whenever possible
- We want to be compatible with all systems and provide all Unicode on all systems

Result is that using a single internal representation would fail at least one of the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for digging this out. I can follow their reasoning although I'm not sure I would end up a the same conclusion. Because all the memory management could have been done under the hood with flags in the C code. But I guess this is opinion based.

Comment: @magu_ I don't understand what you mean by "flags in the C code". If you only have a single utf-8 representation then you lose efficient indexing whenever you use characters with more than one byte. With the current implementation when you are using wide characters you end up with less memory efficiency (even though *it depends*) but with better indexing efficiency. There are still cases where O(1) indexing cannot be achieved but they are much rarer than just using utf-8 where *most* non-English tests would suffer from bad performances.

Comment: my reasoning was that python internals could internally do branching, depending on whenever any character within the string has a value greater or smaller than 127. So one could retain fast indexing fast O(1) indexing for ascii's and the slow O(n) indexing for utf-8. Since `strings` are immutable in `python` this information (any character bigger than 127) could be saved as a flag at object creation.

Comment: @magu_ Yes, but the problem is that is a too common case. Basically **any** non-English test would require O(n) indexing. However it turns out that quite a few languages can be served using a 2-byte representation instead of utf-8 which means those languages can be indexed in O(1) time at the cost of wasting some space for ASCII characters. By the way: the current implementation already work as you say for ASCII text. The difference is what happens with non-ASCII text. They decided to pay some more space to keep O(1) indexing for more texts.